# Could you find the way in this maze of rebuses?

Tags: word, visual, rebus, mazes

Below there is a maze that is made out of small rebuses. And when I say small, I mean really small: every rebus is only 18x18 pixels!

All rebuses can be solved independently from each other, and produces 1-4 letters each. The number of letters tells the direction you have to go, but you have to figure out which number of letters corresponds with which direction (up, right, left, down).

When you are looking for the way to go, you may even get some bonus points! But watch out for dead ends!

I am looking for a final answer that is **a single word** (kind of)

**Original size:**

[image: rebuses maze]

**Same picture, but zoomed in for easier solving:**
[image: rebuses maze zoomed in]

Comment: Beautiful pixel art btw.

Comment: Is it just me or are the rebuses kind of simple? Or am I just being tricked?

Comment: @newQOpenWid With this quantity to solve, I think you'd _want_ them to be simple!

Comment: @newQOpenWid, I guess creating this one was more challenging than solving. And making them more difficult, often makes it impossible and really ambiguous, especially with that few pixels. And I didn't want that. And there are still some rebuses unsolved, so maybe you can help Benjamin to complete his answer ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The hidden question in the rebuses is:

> FOLLOW THE PATH OF THESE REBUSES TO GET THE FINAL ANSWER WHICH IS THE BEST PUZZLING WEBSITE IN THE WORLD

From trying to string together words, we deduce the direction that corresponds to each possible number of letters:

> 1: down, 2: right, 3: left, 4: up

The full maze is visualised below

> Percentage (%) signs indicate the start of a phrase.
>
>  No arrows are shown out of the end of a phrase.
>
>  Uppercase for main path, lowercase for other paths

> ```
>   OW  >  TH  >  E      rr  >  ed  >  he  >  rr  > ings    IN  >  GW  >  E
>   ^^            vv     ^^                                 ^^            vv
>  %FOLL% %stop%  P     utfo    TH  >  EB  >  ES  >  TP  > UZZL  %null%   B
>                 vv     ^^     ^^                                        vv
>   H   < OFT  < ATH    tcho   CHIS   %ex% > tr   >  a      T   < EIN  < SIT
>   vv                   ^^     ^^                   vv     vv
>   E     %pl% >  ea  > sewa   RWHI < SWE  < LAN     r      H     hing <%not%
>   vv                                        ^^     vv     vv
>   S     %bo% >  nu  >  sp  >  oi  >  nt    FINA    e      EW  >  OR  >  LD
>   vv                                        ^^     vv
>   ER  >  EB  >  US  >  ES  >  TO  >  GE  > TTHE    dh  >  er  >  ri  >  ng
> ```

If we remove the following non-solution paths:

> BONUS POINT
>
>  PLEASE WATCH OUT FOR RED HERRINGS
>
>  EXTRA RED HERRING
>
>  NOTHING
>
>  STOP
>
>  NULL

We get the following path (thanks OP @Lezzup)

> ```
>   OW  >  TH  >  E                                         IN  >  GW  >  E
>   ^^            vv                                        ^^            vv
>  FOLL           P             TH  >  EB  >  ES  >  TP  > UZZL           B
>                 vv            ^^                                        vv
>   H   < OFT  < ATH           CHIS                         T   < EIN  < SIT
>   vv                          ^^                          vv
>   E                          RWHI < SWE  < LAN            H
>   vv                                        ^^            vv
>   S                                        FINA           EW  >  OR  >  LD
>   vv                                        ^^
>   ER  >  EB  >  US  >  ES  >  TO  >  GE  > TTHE
> ```

which,

> by following the path of the rebuses as instructed, it gives the three letters `pse`, the initials of `PuzzlingStackExchange` (final answer), which is indeed a puzzling website! Some may even say it's the greatest of them all.

What an amazing puzzle! There were 8 rebuses I had to reverse-engineer (5 on the main path), but I'm glad I worked it out. Credits for a few rebuses are listed below.

Full rebus solution:

1st row:

> OW = OWL - L
>
>  TH = THORIUM = element 90
>
>  E = musical note in bass clef
>
>  RR = pigpen cipher
>
>  ED = character in Ed, Edd n Eddy (thank you @samm82)
>
>  HE = HELIUM = element 2
>
>  RR = Reverse x 2, from a picture of a gear stick
>
>  INGS = RINGS - R
>
>  IN = going INto a door
>
>  GW = 1 million kW (G = giga, meaning 10^12)
>
>  E = e, the mathematical constant, decimal approximation

2nd row:

> FOLL = FALL (autumn, and falling leaves) with A -> O
>
>  STOP = a stop sign
>
>  P = PI - I
>
>  UTFO = UFO placed into the green spots
>
>  TH = pattern 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th
>
>  EB = ELBOW - LOW
>
>  ES = SPAIN = country code top level domain
>
>  TP = TAP - A
>
>  UZZL = [Pentomino naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino)
>
>  NULL = BULL with B -> N
>
>  B = BEE - EE

3rd row:

> H = E + 3 = count up 3 from E: F G H
>
>  OFT = OUT with U -> F
>
>  ATH = BATH - B
>
>  TCHO = MATCH - MA + O
>
>  CHIS = CHI (Greek letter) + S
>
>  EX = IBEX - IB
>
>  TR = TREE - EE
>
>  A = ACORN - CORN
>
>  T = TEA - EA
>
>  EIN = (GENIE - GE) backwards
>
>  SIT = a stick figure sitting on a chair

4th row:

> E = musical note in the treble clef
>
>  PL = POLAND = country code top level domain
>
>  EA = EAR - R
>
>  SEWA = SEWER with ER -> A
>
>  RWHI = R + WHIP - P
>
>  SWE = SWEDEN's [ISO 3166-1 alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) abbreviation (thanks OP @Lezzup)
>
>  LAN = FAN with F -> L
>
>  R = HORSE - HOSE
>
>  H = HAT - AT
>
>  HING = (chess) KING - 3, where H is 3 lower than K: I J K
>
>  NOT = NOTICE - ICE (thanks @samm82)

5th row:

> S = SOUTH (compass direction)
>
>  BO = BOOK - OK (hand signal)
>
>  NU = Greek letter
>
>  SP = Reinterpret the Morse Code of IEAN, ignoring spaces
>
>  OI = Pigpen cipher
>
>  NT = Braille (take the mirror image of this entire rebus)
>
>  FINA = CHINA with CH -> F
>
>  E = mc^2 (mass-energy equivalence)
>
>  EW = EU (European Union) with U -> W
>
>  OR = logic gate symbol
>
>  LD = LED (Light Emitting Diode) - E

6th row

> ER = TV Series running from 1994 to 2009, also red cross = Emergency Room
>
>  EB = EBB (of tide water) - B
>
>  US = United States
>
>  ES = EINSTEINIUM = element 99
>
>  TO = TWO - W
>
>  GE = command for "greater or equal to"
>
>  TTHE = (THETA (Greek letter) - last letter), 4th moved to front
>
>  DH = Norse runes (thanks @samm82)
>
>  ER = HEART - HAT
>
>  RI = Rhode Island
>
>  NG = NU (Katakana) with U -> G

Comment: Some notes: rot13(1. Oheatboreevr frrzf gb or n pebffbire fubj; gur bevtvany fubj vf "Rq, Rqq a Rqql" 2. gur "QU" pbzrf sebz Abefr eharf 3. "nycun zvahf guerr" zvtug whfg zrna "fhogenpg gur ynfg guerr yrggref"? V'z nyfb abg fher)

Comment: 4. "oryy zvahf fabj" zvtug or "abgvpr zvahf vpr = abg"

Comment: As well as explaining each rebus you should really post an image of the path through the maze too, e.g. indicated by a line. A good answer on this site tends to be one which allows someone else to follow your solution path and thought process, to help them understand the puzzle fully - explanation is what we're after... Thanks!

Comment: Now that's much better and I can happily +1 this now as a good and useful answer :) Definitely best to use as few spoilers as possible for the rebuses - the way you've done it here (by row) is perfect; nobody wants to click on 66 individual spoilers! :)

Comment: Thanks @Stiv for your nice note and edits!

Comment: Very well done, @Benjamin! For Sweden, I had ISO-3166 in mind, then you'll know what alpha-3 means ;)

Comment: @Benjamin, did you answer the final question as your own opinion, or did you find the answer in the maze? If you include that last small step as well, then I'll accept the answer. (It may help to color in the maze) If it was just your own opinion, you were only accidentally right :)

Comment: @Lezzup fixed! Indeed I didn't see it previously. Nice touch!

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin's accepted answer is great and amazingly thorough, so I won't go over the solution to every single rebus again. I just want to share how I found the solution because it's more visual and I think it more clearly shows how the rebuses form a maze to reveal the final answer.

Solving each rebus square gives us the following grid:

> [image: An 11x6 grid showing the solution to each rebus puzzle.]

By finding patterns of words and phrases, I deduced that

> 1 letter = Down 
>  2 letters = Right 
>  3 letters = Left, and 
>  4 letters = Up.

Then for each rebus square,

> I knocked down the wall pointing in the corresponding direction to reveal the full layout of the maze (which can be broken up into color-coded sections):
>  [image: An 11x6 grid showing the maze of rebus solutions. Each of 7 distinct areas in the maze is filled with a different color.]

Ignoring all red herrings, the main path through the maze gives us the clue:

> FOLLOW THE PATH OF THESE REBUSES TO GET THE FINAL ANSWER WHICH IS THE BEST PUZZLING WEBSITE IN THE WORLD

and of course,

> the path itself spells out PSE for Puzzling Stack Exchange, the best puzzling site on the world wide web.
>  [image: An 11x6 grid showing the solution to each rebus puzzle. The main path, which spells out the letters PSE, is highlighted in green.]

This was a lot of fun! Thanks for coming up with it.

Comment: Hi Zac, welcome to Puzzling! And the visuals are a great addition to Benjamin's answer. +1